# Solr - Sort search result based on facet count

Tags: solr

I have information of products in Solr and each product is under a category. I would like to sort product search result based on facet count on Category. So if there are 100 products matching criteria under Electronics category and 50 products under Books, I would like to sort the result(or boost) the way that I see first 100 electronics and then 50 books.

Is it possible with one query?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want this feature? maybe results grouping is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible; faceting does not influence search results.